# Do the contents of java.lang.System.properties change with locale?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

I'm not used to having to take i18n stuff into account. I wrote this method for a Java program:

```
boolean isWindows()
{
    return System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows");
}
```

I need this check in order to provide a workaround for a Windows-specific JVM bug.

It occurred to me this program may need to run on systems that do not have English as the chosen language, is that going to cause this line of code to break?

*Maybe I should clarify that I asked this hoping to see what proof people could dredge up (so I feel better about letting this code out into the wild). Answers with links to documentation, experimental evidence, or some kind of supporting rationale get preference.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me get this straight, you are wondering whether OS name (as returned by `os.name` property) might be internationalized and contain the word *windows* in other language?

I would say that for 99% it won't as *Microsoft Windows* is a trademark (or whatever, *IANAL*) and is probably not translated and left as-is. However, I [looked up](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.java#SystemUtils.0IS_OS_WINDOWS) the definition of `IS_OS_WINDOWS` property in Apache Commons Lang [SystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html) class. After removing all the layers of indirection it all boils down to:

```
System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows");
```

I am not claiming this is a proof, but I tend to believe in such well established libraries.

Comment: Yes, your rewording is correct. I'd overlooked SystemUtils, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomasz and Edward said, "os.name" is safe to check with "startWith", but answering *"Do the contents of java.lang.System.properties change with locale?"*, you must notice that, some of properties of [System.getProperties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) may change with locale. Printing properties with different Linux LANGs, I found three properties that changes: "user.country", "user.language" and "sun.jnu.encoding".

Comment: +1 for experimentation. sorry the original question wording was inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")` is safe regardless of locale.